# Amazon s3 authentication error

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am trying to download file from **Amazon s3** using following code

```
    S3Object object = client.getObject(
            new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, sourceFile));
    try (InputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(
            object.getObjectContent())) {
        File file = new File(destination);
        try (OutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {

            int read = -1;
            while ((read = reader.read()) != -1) {
                writer.write(read);
            }
        }
    }
```

Downloading is success but still races peer not authenticated exception

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated